# Как подключится к Bitcoin Node?

Tags: http, websocket, bitcoin, blockchain

Из документации на сайте bitcoin.org я понял что Bitcoin Node — это удаленный сервер участвующий в Blockchain сети. Так же как я понял у каждой Bitcoin Node могут быть свои блоки и транзакции произведенные с участием этой Bitcoin Node. Так же я знаю что Blockchain это полностью открытая система, в которой я могу получить данные о всех производимых транзакциях. К примеру у меня есть какой-нибудь условный ip сервера, который участвует в Blockchain. Как я могу получить всю информацию о блоках и транзакциях этого узла? В частности какие запросы посылать к этим серверам и как взаимодействовать с ними при помощи WebSocket?

Comment: скачайте весь блокчейн официальным клиентом, и смотрите локально, в чём проблема? с какой целью необходимо обращаться к ноде напрямую?

Answer (score 4):

С биткоин нодами нельзя взаимодействовать посредством WebSocket. Для этого существует сетевой протокол биткоин, и о подробностях его работы можете почитать в вики: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Network

Comment: А почему нельзя взаимодействовать с помощью WebSocket, можете объяснить?

Comment: А почему нельзя взаимодействовать с помощью WebSocket, можете объяснить?

Comment: Потому что протокол биткоин работает поверх TCP, и WebSocket работает поверх TCP. Этот как спросить, почему я не могу передать TCP пакет при помощи HTTP.

Comment: Так, хорошо. Если нельзя по веб сокетам, то как тогда?

Comment: Используя TCP. Зачем вам подключаться к чужой ноде, если можно запустить биткоин кор клиент, и обращаться к нему посредством JSON-RPC?

Comment: Мне нужно обращаться к рандомной ноде, не к своей

Answer (score 4):

Если Вам нужна информация от ноды, то Вам самому нужно написать небольшой клиент.

Есть 3 основных клиентов(приложений)

1) полная нода, которая имеет на борту весь блокчейн.

2) SPV нода, которая имеет только заголовки

3) Тонкий кошелек работающий через API какого-нибудь blockchain explorer.

Первый вариант является безопасным и самым сложным(если надумаешь писать клиент). Главный плюс этого варианта - независимость от всех серверов. Ты сам себе сервер.

Второй вариант. Если ты не боишься зависеть от удаленных серверов, то он тебе подходит. Если тебе нужна только информация и осуществление мелких транзакций, то можно воспользоваться им.

Третий вариант самый простой - используй API любого blockchain explorer(так и гугли)
Таким образом сможешь получить необходимую информацию.

Если тебе интересен гибрид второго и третьего, то можешь почитать статью по ссылке ниже:
https://habr.com/ru/post/319862/ - тут рассматривают написание на python простой транзакции и отправка ее в биткойн сеть. Код рабочий, все проверял сам.

Для дальнейшей работы потребуется работать уже вот с этой информацией: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation тут расположена вся документация по протоколу.

План действий:

1) Подключиться к p2p сети bitcoin. Для этого надо знать адрес одного из участников. 
Вот ссылка на исходный код bitcoin core:
https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/chainparams.cpp#L123
она прямая на список доверенных узлов, от которых можно получить список участников p2p сети, для того чтобы в нее войти.

Вот ссылка на подобный продукт, но на python:
https://github.com/ricmoo/pycoind/blob/master/pycoind/coins/bitcoin.py#L41 тут тоже эти же ссылки.

Для того, чтобы подключиться к этим серверам, можно воспользоваться кодом по этой ссылке:
https://github.com/ricmoo/pycoind/blob/33a600e617ec89c5a0f680ce7725b777d6176ea8/pycoind/util/bootstrap.py#L28 
Код на второй питон, но можно переписать легко на третий. На работоспособность проверял. С его помощью ты легко получишь список адресов p2p сети.

2) когда мы получили список узлов, нам потребуется отправить(с помощью python socket например) некоторым узлам пакет, который будет содержать в себе транзакцию/запрос получение блока/etc.
Для написания пакетов я брал вот эту документацию:
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation тут все необходимое. По правде говоря, ее достаточно для общения с узлами, но тебе, скорее всего, будет непонятно, поэтому читай на хабре как собирать пакет для биткойна вот по этой ссылке https://habr.com/ru/post/319862/  там с рабочими примерами.